# Button enabled throughjs function goes back to disabled state

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form with two buttons and some texareas. As the second one should only be available after the first has been clicked I set it to disabled as default and then enable it with a js function call. That works. However when the first button is clicked some php code is executed (*through if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")*) and after that php code has been executed the button goes back to the disabled state.

Any ideas why? I seems that the whole form is reloaded once the php is done but I don't know why.

Here's the code for the buttons and js function:

```
<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="enableButton2()"/>
   
<input id="saveFile" class="button_text" type="submit" name="download" value="Download" disabled/>

<script>
    function enableButton2() {
        document.getElementById("saveFile").disabled = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: IF you post your form without ***AJAX***, the entire page is reloaded after the form is submitted so everything come back to initial state, try remove "type" attribute from the first button and use AJAX to make POST request... If you want to submit only with the second button, take a look at preventDefault() to prevent form submit. `function enableButton2(e) { e.preventDefault(); //---- YOUR AJAX POST HERE -- 
 document.getElementById("saveFile").disabled = false; }`

Comment: Never done anything with AJAX so I'd rather avoid if possible (I'm a network engineer and this website is just for the output of a script).
The second button triggers a file download. However the proper file will only be there once you clicked the first button.
I'm trying with inserting the 'disabled' in the input attributes via a php variable but that doesn't seem to work either:
<input id="saveFile" class="button_text" type="submit" name="download" value="Download" <?php echo $button_disabled;?> />
$button_disabled is set to "disabled" and changed to "" once button1 is clicked.

Comment: To execute your PHP you MUST post your form, if you POST your form without ajax the page is reloading...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to post your form with first button then is response is ok (mean your php was executed and return something), the second button is enabled else it display error.

```js
function enableButton2() {
  var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
  fetch("YOUR-URL", { //Edit YOUR-URL to your .php script
    method: "POST",
    body: form
  }).then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      //Put your code here if form successfully submitted
      document.getElementById('saveFile').disabled = false;
    } else {
      //Put your code here if form successfully submitted but return something else than HTTP 200 Status
      console.log('Network error');
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    //Put your code here if form unsuccessfully submitted
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}
```

```html
<form action=# id="form">
  <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="enableButton2()" />
  <input id="saveFile" class="button_text" type="submit" name="download" value="Download" disabled />
</form>
```